# Smallest, simplest possible (randomly) flashing 2-3 LED circuit

Tags: led, battery-operated

I am trying to randomly flash 2-3 LEDs using the smallest possible circuit using 1 or 2 CR2032 batteries. Can I power 2-3 3mm (3-3.4v, 20mA)(amber, white) flashing (slow 1Hz) LEDs using one CR2032 battery? Can I get them to flash at different rates by using a 2nd battery? I found this project that uses only the flashing LEDs and a battery...http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rj5tqhGypAE&feature=player_embedded
...but I think that may drain the battery too quickly since there are no resisitors used, is that correct?
I have read this question but I do not have the power requirements of the IR LED.

Comment: Is the imitation of cloud-to-cloud lightning relevant to this question?

Comment: I think it is relevant to the effect I am trying to achieve.

Comment: To get out of preparing treats, I once did a Halloween pumpkin lighting circuit that simulated lighting flashes (bright white and very brief) and eerie green echos, but I used a microcontroller. It was very simple (3 AA cells for power).

Comment: @user38698 Is it relevant to know to be able to satisfactorily answer the question?

Comment: Spehro, 3 AA cells are too big for this project.

Comment: Andy aka, ...only in that it is a good visual example of what I am ultimately trying to achieve with the project. I can edit out the line if it is disturbing to you...

Comment: This sounds like a job for an Arduino. Cheap, easy to learn, low power requirements, has PWM outputs.

Comment: Polynomial, is that because of the lights flashing at different rates? The linked project simply uses flashing LEDs and a CR2032 battery, period.

Comment: I think random flashing LEDs will yield an effect that is lame, at best.

Comment: Spehro, I think you may be right. So Arduino or is there something else I can use...Adafruit has Gemma and neopixels.

Comment: You could use a microcontroller, but there's a learning curve. Here's some comments from my code: 
   The green LEDs sequence with 20-25% duty cycle, one on at a time. 
   The white flashes for 0.1 second every 3.9 seconds, followed 0.3 seconds
   later by the dimmer white/blue for 0.1 second. 

   Since they are out of sync, there is a sort of random effect without it
   really being random.

Comment: You can easily power a small MCU and 3 LEDs from a CR2032, but not at 20mA each.

Answer (score 1):

lets start with Specs. and assumptions;

CR2032 Nominal Voltage: 3.0 Volts
Typical Capacity: 240 mAh (to 2.0 volts)
(**Rated at 15KΩ** at 21°C)
Battery ESR ~ 3kΩ

Red & Yellow LED = 1mA@1.9V , 20mA@ 2.2V +/-10% Voltage 
thus from 1~20mA, **ESR=** 0.3V/20mA = **15Ω**

let Flash time duration = 100ms   RC=0.1 , R=15Ω ∴C = 0.1/15 =6,600 μF,
 ∴ consider lower duration as this will cause problems for charge time

**Resistance ratio = R_bat/R_led = 3,000Ω/15Ω = 200** which means charge time is 20 seconds and thus either one needs to reduce battery reistance ( bigger battery ) or raise LED resistance ( lower current from 20mA to 2mA ) or reduce flash duration (preferred).

(Take 2)
Let Flash duration = 10ms, C= 660 μF and consider raising LED current to 30mA

Compute Charge time from discharge Vmin to Vmax voltage:

Vmin = LED threshold , e.g. 1.6V for Red,Yellow
Vmax = 3V max, or less depends on charge time, eg RC rise time, ∆V=63%

T = R_bat*C = 3kΩ * 660 μF =2 seconds.  where T is defined as ∆V=63%
thus after T charge time Vcap= where  3-1.6V = 1.4V  ∆V=63%*1.4=0.9V
∴Vcap=0.9+1.6=2.5V

Simple solution might be a 5Hz CMOS gate relaxation oscillator (Schmitt inverter with 10MΩ feedback R, 1uF cap to gnd) driving a MOSFET in series with LED on Drain to  660uF cap which is in parallel with CR2032 battery

You can make your own Parts List and schematic for Q, two C's, one R1, one LED, one battery.

Random ? go digital.

I wanted to show the analog design process, not the solution.
A digital solution can be done by others.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgOKRp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Yes the base of the transistor is open circuit)

Adapted from: http://cappels.org/dproj/simplest_LED_flasher/Simplest_LED_Flasher_Circuit.html

You can use 2 of these: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12624 if you want to use something rechargeable and still small.

Comment: While cute, I don't think that will work at 7.2V. Despite the 5V or 6V rating, most EB junctions break down at around 9V, so you need about a 12V supply.

Comment: That's probably a good point, maybe you can try with 3 cells in series.

Comment: Thanks for the links and the sup0er simple circuit. I would need 3 CR2032's for this to operate?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I power 2-3 3mm (3-3.4v, 20mA)(amber, white) flashing (slow 1Hz) LEDs using one CR2032 battery?

Yes, but one CR2032? Without knowing the current draw of the leds, no way of telling how long the battery will last.

> but I think that may drain the battery too quickly since there are no resisitors used, is that correct?

Nope. These flashing leds arn't pure light emitting diodes. They are diodes, resistors, and microcontrollers in a super small package. Even with the bare eye, you can make out a small black square and bond wire(s). Under a microscope, it's even more obvious. The 5050 sized package below is a big example of it:
[image]

AND to add to that, cr2032 batteries are low capacity batteries (~200mAH) designed for long term small current uses. With high ESR (Equivalent Series Resistance). It essentially acts like a resistor in series with the load. You can take a bare 3.4v led, hook it up to a fresh cr2032, and it will not blow the led. For two reasons. As the current draw on the battery increases, the voltage drops due to the battery chemistry. Which causes the led to draw less current. It's a balancing act. And a 3.3v 20mA led's voltage vs current curve. 3v through a 3.3v led will limit how much current the led can draw as well. It's more complicated than that with normal batteries, but a cr2032 or similar type are a specific case. (In my experiences, even a 1.8v led with a cr2032 will not blow, because of the ESR). Heck, most dollar store led flashlights use these characteristics of leds and batteries to limit material to "case + battery + led". No resistor needed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, good information. I was thinking of using 1.8mm but I can't find flashing LEDs in that size. So, do you think 2 CR2032's would operate 3 3mm, 3v, 20mA flashing LEDs? WOuld they flash at the same rate?